# MockMultipartFile is not included in MockHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, junit

I wanna test what happens when the oversized image file is sent to spring boot server using MockMultipartFile.

```java
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class PostControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    void overSizePostUploadTest() throws Exception {
        SignUpRequest signUpRequest = addMember();
        Cookie cookie = login(signUpRequest);

        String originalFilename = "image_of_17MB.jpg";

        try (InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(originalFilename);) {
            MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("image", originalFilename, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, inputStream);

            ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/posts")
                    .file(file)
                    .param("title", "this is title")
                    .param("content", "this is content")
                    .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                    .cookie(cookie)
            );
            actions.andExpect(status().isBadRequest());
        }
    }
}
```

[image location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShRue.png)

And the result is like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0LQl.png)

The MockMultipartFile is not included in MockHttpServletRequest.
What's the cause of this trouble??

I think MockMultipartFile should be included in MockHttpServletRequest.

Answer (score 2):

Work of Resolving multipart is done by tomcat side.

However, by default, @SpringBootTest provides a mock web environment which means that embedded tomcat server is not started.
Also, MockMvc provides testing without running a tomcat server to acheive lightweight tests.

To test that tomcat resolves multipart, embedded tomcat server should be started which can be done by setting up `@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)` and using TestRestTemplate or WebTestClient instead of MockMvc.

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I had a similar Issue for `MockServletRegistration` [as you can see here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31425).

From what I can tell,

1. you need a concrete usecase
2. they need to plan the introduction of `MockMultipartFile`

If both exists, you can make a feature-request.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I got to know that MockMvc provices testing without running a tomcat server.